# MockK failes to mock functions defined outside of their class

Tags: kotlin, mockk

As far as I see, MockK fails to mock functions, which are defined on package level (and not in the class they belong to). Here is a small example:

```
package some.package

class A {}
class B {}

fun A.getB() : B {
  println("real getB called!")
  return B()
}
```

And a class to test it:

```
class Test {

  @MockK
  private lateinit var a : A

  @BeforeMethod
  fun setUp() {
    init(this)
    val bMock = mockk<B>()
    every { a.getB() } returns bMock
  }

  @Test
  fun test() {
    a.getB()
  }
}
```

This test fails with a message like `Missing calls inside every { ... } block`. But if I move the function `getB()` into the class `A`, then the test succeeds. I could not find any documentation on this behaviour. Is there any workaround for this? Unfortunately, in my real project I have no possiblity to move the function into the class. Is there any other way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reference the extension function you are mocking with `mockkStatic`. This is for extension functions outside the classes.

`mockkStatic(a::getB)`

Comment: Yep, thanks! But not with a::getB as argument, but the package and file name as String, so in my case (assuming, File.kt is the file name): mockkStatic("some.package.FileKt")

Comment: Yes, that's another way to reference multiple extension functions in a file.